# error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*' when declaring pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree

This is header file for my binary tree.
I have a class called TreeNode and of course BinaryTree class have a pointer to its root.

And I got following Three errors

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

And Code for BinaryTree header file

```
#pragma once

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "Node.h"
using namespace std;

class BinaryTreeStorage
{
private:
    TreeNode* root;

public:
    //Constructor
    BinaryTreeStorage(void);

    //Gang Of Three
    ~BinaryTreeStorage(void);
    BinaryTreeStorage(const BinaryTreeStorage & newBinaryTreeStorage);
    BinaryTreeStorage& operator=(const BinaryTreeStorage & rhs);

    //Reading and writing
    ofstream& write(ofstream& fout);
    ifstream& read(ifstream& fin);

};

//Streaming
ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& fout, const BinaryTreeStorage& rhs);
ifstream& operator>>(ifstream& fin, const BinaryTreeStorage& rhs);
```

error appears to be at line 11

```
    TreeNode* root;
```

I have spent few days trying to get rid of this error and completely devastated.

Is this error about wrong namespace ? Or maybe TreeNode class not declared right?

And just in case code for TreeNode header file

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "BinaryTreeStorage.h"

using namespace std;

class TreeNode
{
private:
    string name;
    TreeNode* left;
    TreeNode* right;

public:
    //Constructor
    TreeNode(void);
    TreeNode(string data);

    //Gang of Three
    ~TreeNode(void);
    TreeNode(const TreeNode* copyTreeNode);


    //Reading and writing
    ofstream& write(ofstream& fout);

    //Add TreeNode
    void addTreeNode(string data);

    //Copy tree
    void copy(TreeNode* root);
};
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you everyone for answering question, this was stupid one indeed. Thats what happens if you program C# before C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
#include "Node.h"
```

simply forward declare the class:

```
class TreeNode;
```

Also, why are you including `BinaryTreeStorage.h` in `Node.h`? There's no need for it, so remove it.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Node.h is including BinaryTreeStorage.h, so when you try to compile Node.h (the class TreeNode) it first compiles BinaryTreeStorage, but that requires knowing what TreeNode is which hasn't been compiled yet.

The way around this is to forward declare the class:

```
    class TreeNode;
```

which tells the compiler to expect a class of type TreeNode to be defined later on, but you can declare pointers and references of that type in the meantime.  The last thing to do is then remove the `#include "Node.h"`.  This breaks your circular reference.

Comment: TY for the insight about circular references, it helped to solve my problem! +1

Answer (score 0):

You're using `ofstream` in the definition of `TreeNode` class, but you've not included this:

```
#include <fstream> //include this in Node.h
```

Please do so.

Also, there is no need of inclusion of `BinaryTreeStorage.h` in `Node.h`. It makes thing circular.

Answer (score 0):

Forward declare TreeNode i.e., add `class TreeNode;` before `class BinaryTreeStorage{};`